# how can i convert audio file to mpg file entirely in nodejs

Tags: node.js

basically i am web developer so i have not much of an idea what to do. OR what to research at all. I want to make like exe file in nodejs that would

- take any audio file within it's directory
- convert them into mpg file with one default photo ('abc.jpg') for a
  video.

Optional:-

- analyze sound and animate the circle's radius based on that and save
  that as a video along the audio, as opposed to static image.

While, i'd really appreciate the whole solution and code for hardest parts however any useful hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, **ffmpeg command line** can convert an audio file to video with an image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887311/ffmpeg-1-image-1-audio-file-1-video

**Call ffmpeg in node.js application:**

```
$ npm install fluent-ffmpeg
```

Example: *convert image to video*

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: '/path/to/your_image.jpg', nolog: true })
  // loop for 5 seconds
  .loop(5)
  // using 25 fps
  .withFps(25)
  // save to file
  .saveToFile('/path/to/your_target.m4v', function(retcode, error){
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  });
```

fluent-ffmpeg just spawn a ffmpeg process to convert audio/video. If you don't like to to spawn a new process you can use ffmpeg C/C++ and recomplile them as a node.js addon, but I don't think that a good choice :)

Comment: wow this solves the problem like 80% of it. let me try this and get back to you.